# Some css styles removed when drag and dropped html inside contenteditable element

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, native, contenteditable

I am using native HTML5 drag and drop to drop some part of HTML into contenteditable element (contenteditable="true")..

problem is next: 
some css styles are removed when item is dropped. It looks like some optimization is happened, for example if we have element with color:red and we drop it into droppable area this css property is removed because some of his parents have this same property and value..

for example:

```js
$(function () {
        $('.draggablePlaceholder').attr("contenteditable", false);
        $('.draggablePlaceholder').off('dragstart').on('dragstart', function (e) {   
            var dataToSend = $(e.target).attr("data-value");
            e.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData($(e.target).attr("data-value-type"), $(e.target).attr("data-value"))
        });
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="color: red;" contenteditable="true">
            drop here...
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>


<span class="draggablePlaceholder" draggable="true" contenteditable="false" 
data-value="<table>
         <tbody><tr>
          <td style=&quot; color:red; font-size:19px; &quot;>SOME TEXT</td>
         </tr>
        </tbody></table>" data-value-type="text/html">
ITEM FOR DRAG
</span>
```

when you try to move "SOME TEXT" into droppable area the result is:
1 css property: font-size:19px;
instead of 2 css properties: color:red; font-size:19px;

so color:red is removed

is there way to skip this "optimization", so original code is copied?